# What are the advantages of route maps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to Express.

I've just learned [Route mapping](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.13.1/examples/route-map/index.js?_ga=1.58724783.361048551.1458672114#L52-L66) and I can't imagine future usage of similar code:

```
app.map({

'/users': {
    get: users.list,

    '/:id': {
        get: users.view,

        '/edit': {
            get: users.edit,
            put: users.update
        }
    }
}
```

**Why** would you want to structure your code this way?

1. You introduce your own function `map()` instead of using tools Express already has available for routing (like Router).
2. Also, you define middleware functions as methods of objects. Exporting them [directly](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.13.1/examples/route-separation/user.js?&_ga=1.58724783.361048551.1458672114#L31) seems a more elegant solution.

Are there any advantages of using such "mapping" approach?

Or is it simply a matter of aesthetics - someone else considers this the more elegant solution than Router/route separation?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: As you might have guessed, the modular approach that you already know of is the best way to go. Most likely, internally, this is the kind of structure that `express` might be generating and querying against when a request comes in.